# emjer.js view not reading context

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

I have the following js, based on the emberjs.com routing tutorial.  The var 'wontAppear' wont map in the corrsponding view.

```
Quiz = Em.Application.create({
ApplicationView: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'App'
}),
IntroSettings : Ember.Object.extend(),
ApplicationController: Ember.Controller.extend({
    titlebar: 'My New App',
}),

IntroView: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'Intro'
}),
IntroController: Em.ObjectController.extend({ house: "2" }),

CountDownView: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'CountDown',
    didInsertElement: function () {
        this.$().hide().show('drop', { direction: "right" }, 200);
    },
}),
CountDownController: Em.ObjectController.extend({

}),

Router: Em.Router.extend({
    enableLogging: true,
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('body','Intro');
            },
            countDown: Ember.Route.transitionTo('countDown')
        }),
        countDown: Ember.Route.extend({
            connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('body', 'CountDown',     { wontAppear: "5" });
            }
        })
    })
})
});


Quiz.initialize();
```

the views are setup thus :

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars"  data-template-name="App">
    <div id="quiz-container">
        <div id="headerPanel">
            <div class="title">{{titlebar}}</div>
            <div class="timerDiv"> </div>
            <div class="timerDivText"></div>
        </div>
        {{outlet body}}
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="Intro">
    <div id="introPanel">
        <img id="helpimg" src="images/helpimage.jpg" />
        <button id="startButton" {{action "countDown" on="click"}}>Start Game</button>
    </div>
</script>

<script  type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="CountDown">
    <div class="countdown">
        {{wontAppear}}
    </div>
</script>
```

The only way i can get data to appear in the view is to add it to the application controller.  I thought as the countdown view would get the data from it's corresponding countdownController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you (and the sample you're reading in [the primer](http://emberjs.com/guides/router_primer/)) are missing a newly added property in the Application namespace.

Ember now automatically starts the app on its own, so you don't need to call `App.initialize()` (`Quiz.initialize()` in you case), however, if you want/need to, you can set the `autoinit` of your app to **false** and you won't have any trouble calling `App.initialize()`. If you don't set it to false and call the initialize, Ember will throw an exception saying that you can't call initialize multiple times.

Another thing, naming/casing conventions do matter when you're working with any Framework, it's not different with Ember, so your `connectOutlet` should be something like this:

```
// ... other code
// note that "countDown" starts with a lower cased "c"
router.get('applicationController')
      .connectOutlet(
          'body', /* outlet name*/
          'countDown', /* view/controller pair name in cammelCase */
          { wontAppear: "5" } /* your context object*/
      );
// ... other code
```

Your app will still throw an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property '#' of object # is not a
>   function

But I'm not sure what that's about, I was just trying to solve this particular issue with the call of `connectOutlet` in your `countDown` route.

See a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/MwXjG/16/)** of this example

Comment: It was the casing of 'CountDown' that was causing the problem, thanks!  I had read a that ember camel-cases the instances internally but hadn't thought to apply it here for some reason.

Comment: Extra kudos for the fiddle!  I'd been trying out how to setup an ember fiddle, great template for it.